# Is there something bad will happend when construct multi level dispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

### Snippet 1

```
let workerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "foo")
workderQueue.async {
   #code
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       #code
      workerQueue.async {
            #code

      }
   }
}
```

### Snippet 2

```
let workerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "foo")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   #code
   workerQueue.async {
       #code
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
            #code

      }
   }
}
```

Is it ok to write code like snippet 1 or snippet 2 ? Will the main thread be blocked?

Comment: Please do not ask a broad question that is not asking a specific or clear statement.  Describe what you are looking to perform or ask. This site is for programming related questions as defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  This site is not used for code debugging and comparing code snippets nor is it to ask if a piece of code should work. For code reviewing check out here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there’s nothing inherently “bad” with these patterns.

That having been said, the typical pattern is:

```
workerQueue.async {
    // do something computationally intensive

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // update UI and/or model
    }
}
```

And this is motivated by “I have something sufficiently intensive that I don’t want it running on the main queue (and adversely affecting the UX), but when I’m done, I need to update my UI and/or the model.”

It’s pretty rare that you also have a further level of nesting that says “and when I’m done updating the UI, I need to dispatch something else back to my same worker queue”, as shown in your first example. If you have a practical example of that, perhaps you can share it with us, as there might be more elegant ways of refactoring that to avoid a “tower” of nested dispatches, which can start to render the code a little hard to follow.

In your second example, where you’re dispatching to the main thread first is also a bit atypical. (Yes, we occasionally have to do that, but it’s less common.) I guess you’re presuming you’re already on some other thread (though not always). If that’s the case, where the code is expecting you to be on a particular thread, you might want to make that assumption explicit, e.g.:

```
func foo() {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(workerQueue))

    // do some stuff that should be on the `workerQueue`

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // update UI, etc.

        ...
    }
}
```

Bottom line, there’s absolutely no problem with an arbitrary level of nesting, especially if doing it with `async` ... doing this with `sync` can invite deadlock problems if you’re not careful. But from a practical “can future programmers read this code and clearly deduce what the resulting behavior is going to be”, you will often want to constrain this so it’s not too confusing.

---

As a practical example I might be doing something on some dedicate functional queue (e.g. a database access queue or an image processing queue), and I might need to use another synchronization queue to ensure thread-safe access, and I might need to do UI updates on the main queue. But I don’t generally have this tower of three levels of queues, but, for example, I encapsulate these various levels to avoid confusion (e.g. I have a reader-writer generic that encapsulates the details of that concurrent queue I use for thread-safe access), and my code avoids complicated intermingling different types of dispatch queues in any given method. At any particular level of abstraction I’m trying to avoid too many different queue types at one time.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to execute code on desired thread, if you are on some another thread.

For example, Since by default app runs on main thread. But if a task runs on Background thread and modifies UI element within itself, then it should be enclosed in main thread.

```
some_background/other_thread_task {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
       //UI Update
       self.myTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your snippets are the same structure. That structure is totally normal and is exactly how to switch threads.